# Доступ к переменным класса родителя C++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Только недавно начал изучать ООП. Решил создать 2 класса: класс точки и производный класс линии. Вот что получилось:

```
class point
{
    protected:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        point ( int a, int b ): x(a), y(b) {}
        point () { x=0; y=0; }
};

class line : public point
{
    private:
        point a;
        point b;
    public:
        line ( point aa, point bb ): a(aa), b(bb) {};
        float len ()
        {
            ...
        }
};
```

Не понимаю как получить доступ к переменным класса-родителя чтобы вычислить длину отрезка. Хотелось бы чтобы вместо пропуска был код, похожий на этот:

```
int dx = abs(a.x - b.x);
int dy = abs(a.y - b.y);
float l = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
return l;
```

При подстановке данного кода на место пропуска получается

```
user@user:~$ g++ oop.cpp 
oop.cpp: In member function ‘float line::len()’:
oop.cpp:23:28: error: ‘int point::x’ is protected within this context
   23 |             int dx = abs(a.x - b.x);
      |                            ^
oop.cpp:7:13: note: declared protected here
    7 |         int x;
      |             ^
oop.cpp:23:34: error: ‘int point::x’ is protected within this context
   23 |             int dx = abs(a.x - b.x);
      |                                  ^
oop.cpp:7:13: note: declared protected here
    7 |         int x;
      |             ^
oop.cpp:24:28: error: ‘int point::y’ is protected within this context
   24 |             int dy = abs(a.y - b.y);
      |                            ^
oop.cpp:8:13: note: declared protected here
    8 |         int y;
      |             ^
oop.cpp:24:34: error: ‘int point::y’ is protected within this context
   24 |             int dy = abs(a.y - b.y);
      |                                  ^
oop.cpp:8:13: note: declared protected here
    8 |         int y;
      |             ^
```

Comment: Отрезок не является точкой, т..е. наследование здесь не логично, не нужно. А у точек должен быть способ получить координаты снаружи - публичные поля или методы-аксессоры. Если это поправить, то заработает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И зачем здесь наследование?
Получается, что ваша "линия" (отрезок) — это точка, в которую входят на правах членов еще две точки? Зачем столько? :)

К членам точки, наследником которой является `line`, вы можете обращаться свободно, типа `x += y` :), а вот обращение к членам точек `a` и `b` — это уже *извне*, так сказать... и наследование тут ни при чем.

Так что можно сделать поля в `point` открытыми (сделать класс структурой) — что для такого простого класса-данных вполне оправданно. Можно добавить в класс `point` функции для получения значений `x` и `y` ("геттеры") и использовать их. Можно сделать класс `line` другом, типа

```
class line;

class point
{
    ...
    friend class line;
};

class line
{
    ...
        float len ()
        {
            int dx = abs(a.x - b.x);
            int dy = abs(a.y - b.y);
            float l = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            return l;
        }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Первое сообщение компилятора говорит
в позиции 23:28 стоит обращение к protected-члену a.x и компилятор ругается: так низззя, такой доступ запрещён!
Сделай для членов функции-геттеры.
Рекомендую почитать самоучитель для быстрого освоения материала на сайте radioprog или ravesli